# How best to handle unknown object names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am writing a generic procedure and I don't understand how to handle names of objects that are unknown. In this case I am loading all *.Rda files in a directory and doing rbind to make a data frame. The names and number of Rda files can vary. My question is how best to handle this situation?

```r
library(data.table)
# Load all data frames in wd
my_files <- list.files(pattern='*.Rda',full.names = TRUE)
# Names of files without .Rda suffix
my_files_names <- gsub(".Rda$","",list.files(pattern='*.Rda'))
# load each data frame, creates objects with names in my_files_names
for(i in 1:length(my_files)){
  load(my_files[i])
}
# make large data frame from all loaded data frames
combined_df <- rbindlist(my_files_names)
```

I am getting the error
`Input is character but should be a plain list of items to be stacked`

`combined_df <- rbindlist(as.list(my_files_names))` doesn't work.

The example works using `rbind` with each object as an argument, but for some reason a character vector can't be used to refer to objects with names not known at run-time. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you actually need the names of the objects downstream your code? because if not you could try with something like: `combined_df <- my_files %>% lapply(., load) %>% rbindlist()` using `library(magrittr)` for the `%>%` pipes (I do not have your data so I cannot test it). Be aware of @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's comment and make sure that your objects only contain a data.frame for this kind of solution to work

Comment: The `.Rda` files only contain one data frame. Thank you @davidnortes for the suggestion. The names are not important. Your suggestion is giving me an error `Error in rbindlist(.) :  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list`. I've also tried  `combined_df <- bind_rows(lapply(my_files, load))`  but that doesn't work either.

Comment: if your Rda files has one data.frame why not use RDS files instead?

Comment: @jangorecki yes, Rds would be better. These files were created by another user though... I will test if this problem is related to Rda/Rds. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Creating `rds` files and using them worked. I assume the problem came from the `rda` format but I'm not certain. `my_files <- list.files(pattern='*.rds',full.names = TRUE)` and then `combined_df <- bind_rows(lapply(my_files, readRDS))` worked.

Comment: @quantixed Indeed. I've been doing tests and `lapply(., load)` does not work as expected with _Rda_

Comment: @quantixed please self answer your question, so it will not hang like this being unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a two-liner:

```r
library(dplyr)
my_files <- list.files(pattern='*.rds',full.names = TRUE)
combined_df <- bind_rows(lapply(my_files, readRDS))
```

First, the names of the objects were not important so I could this different approach. Second, the use of `.Rda` files was causing problems. This file type can contain more than one object. Although my files only had a single data frame per file, the code about would not run with `load` as an argument in `lapply`. I converted my files to `.rds` files, which only allow one data frame per file and the code ran fine.